# Rails: text_method of collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following is an extract from API for collection_select method:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

My collection is the array of strings.  In the **text_method** I would like to output the modified string gsub(some regex stuff).  What is the best way of doing it? I could think of reopening String class and implementing something for text_method but if would imagine its not really nice way.

Thanks.

Comment: What does this do / where did it come from? Array already has a [select method](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Array#select-instance_method).

Comment: It comes from a form select box value.  So if I'll use f.select instead of f.collection_select I would conceptually face the same problem, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three options what you could do:

1. What you have noticed in your question: Open the String class, define a (very special) method like `myapp_gsub` (without arguments) and include that as `text_method`.
2. Define a model class, include the model objects in your collection, and define inside the model object a text method.
3. Alias the method `ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper#options_from_collection_for_select` and add the option that the `text_method` can be a block. Then you are free to define the text_method as well as block. I would not recommend that if you are not completely sure what the impact of that "enhancement" is.

So opening the `String` class would be the easiest option, in my opinion.

Comment: From the given options I have to agree that reopening a String is the best way.  Just done that, doesn't look as non-pretty as I thought.

Comment: I prefer the second option. Modifying the built-in classes never feels safe to me, and since `collection_sort` is a Rails construct, we likely have a model lying around anyway.